# Microstrategy Counting comma delimited text in a field separately in a chart

Tags: analytics, business-intelligence, microstrategy

Do you have all any idea how would you take a field that has comma delimited text in it (with a possible of 20 selections or so) and break them out in a pie chart in microstrategy?  For example, if one of the line items in the field were "Apple, Pear, Orange" making the pie chart look at that field and instead of putting on the pie chart that there were 1 "Apple, Pear, Orange" putting that there were 1 Apple, 1 Pear, 1 Orange (Counting them separately) in the pie chart.